# How to Scroll Back after use "ScrollWindowEx" in VC++

Tags: mfc, scroll

I want to scroll spacial area in PropertySheet.

To scroll this area, I use:

```
ScrollWindowEx(0, nDelta, &rect, NULL, NULL, rect1,
               SW_SCROLLCHILDREN | SW_INVALIDATE | SW_ERASE );
```

Scrollup is ok.

But can not scroll back.

Any one know why ?

And how to solve it ?

Thanks!

Comment: "But can not scroll back" Why?

Comment: Read the documentation, please. if nDelta is positive, then up. If nDelta is negative, then down.

Comment: If I use "ScrollWindowEx(0, nDelta, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
               SW_SCROLLCHILDREN | SW_INVALIDATE | SW_ERASE );" can scroll up and scroll down, nothing disappear. But this is not I want.I want to scroll special area. So I try use "ScrollWindowEx(0, nDelta, rect, NULL, NULL, NULL,
               SW_SCROLLCHILDREN | SW_INVALIDATE | SW_ERASE );", This will disappeared after scrolling down?

Comment: When you want to scroll "back", you need to offset the rect argument with the nDelta value, possibly with ::OffsetRect. The "rect" to scroll down is not the one you scrolled up.